# How to update calendar package

Tags: python, calendar

I have a calendar package which contains list of working days in different regions in the world. This is so that the code only runs on working days. My issue is that it only contains dates for up to this year end as package maintainers have to update the list continually. So my question what can i do so as to get an updated calendar and overwrite the calendar which i have now every few weeks? I ask because i will convert my code to .exe and thus i am looking for a way so i dont have to put out a new .exe file manually.

The package i have used is called: `trading_calander` from [here](https://github.com/quantopian/trading_calendars). 
I used `pip` to install it:
`pip install trading-calendars`

This package produces a list like this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-06-02 00:00:00+00:00', '2010-06-03 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2010-06-04 00:00:00+00:00', '2010-06-07 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2010-06-08 00:00:00+00:00', '2010-06-09 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2010-06-10 00:00:00+00:00', '2010-06-11 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2010-06-14 00:00:00+00:00', '2010-06-15 00:00:00+00:00',
               ...
               '2020-09-21 00:00:00+00:00', '2020-09-22 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2020-09-23 00:00:00+00:00', '2020-09-24 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2020-09-25 00:00:00+00:00', '2020-09-28 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2020-09-29 00:00:00+00:00', '2020-09-30 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2020-10-01 00:00:00+00:00', '2020-10-05 00:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', length=2556, freq='C')
```

Comment: You need to specify what package you speak of to begin with... Was it originally installed with `pip`, `anaconda`, `brew`? Question needs more detail.

Comment: @Felipe i have updated the question as requested.